# mysql trigger with select from database and update a column

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have this trigger. If the incoming log agrees with input filter, than is not saved into database. But, I want to keep number of "hits" of each Primitive_filter. I have a column named hit_rate, which is int(30). Is there some way how to do that? Maybe specific error? Or sth else? Thx for help.

```
UPDATE Primitive_filters SET hit_rate = hit_rate + 1 where Primitive_filters.id = ???;
```

trigger

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER inputFilter
before insert
on Logs
for each row
begin
declare msg varchar(255);
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Primitive_filters, Primitive_in_filter, Filters WHERE 
Filters.name = "input" AND Filters.id = Primitive_in_filter.id_filter AND Primitive_in_filter.id_primitive = Primitive_filters.id AND
(Primitive_filters.id_host LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT host FROM Hosts WHERE id = new.id_host),'%') OR Primitive_filters.id_host IS NULL) AND
(Primitive_filters.facility LIKE CONCAT('%',new.facility,'%') OR Primitive_filters.facility IS NULL) AND
(Primitive_filters.priority LIKE CONCAT('%',new.priority,'%') OR Primitive_filters.priority IS NULL) AND
(Primitive_filters.program LIKE CONCAT('%',new.program,'%') OR Primitive_filters.program IS NULL) AND
(new.msg REGEXP Primitive_filters.msg OR Primitive_filters.msg IS NULL)) > 0 THEN CALL raise_error; END IF; 
END //

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is NOT the answer to your question.**

It's only a hint how to fix a potentially serious performance problem in your code.
Don't use this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... giant query ...) > 0 
THEN CALL raise_error; 
END IF;
```

Use this instead:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... giant query ...)
THEN CALL raise_error; 
END IF;
```

The former condition calculates a count ... it **must** read all rows returned by the query
If the query returns billion rows, it must reads them all --> because you asked `give me a count of rows`.
Then, after the query return the count, there is a check:   if the query returns at least **one row**, then do something.

The latter condition stops executing the query when the query returns first row, saving time and resources.